# java.util.NoSuchElementException when trying to send Messages with RabbitMQ and Spring

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I am building a service that sends email objects through RabbitMQ. There is already another service that works, that receives the objects and sends actual emails to users.

I get the following exception when I run my tests during the setup when Spring tries to run the spring app:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeyIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:742)
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.next(Collections.java:1042)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.initialize(RabbitAdmin.java:438)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$9(RabbitAdmin.java:402)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CompositeConnectionListener.onCreate(CompositeConnectionListener.java:36)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:566)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1773)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1748)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1729)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.declareQueue(RabbitAdmin.java:219)
at it.com.my.app.mgmt.user.EmailSenderIT.setup(EmailSenderIT.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

This is the mail sender:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class QueueEmailSender implements EmailSender {

private final AmqpTemplate mqTemplate;
private final AmqpAdmin mqAdmin;
private final String queueName;
private final String exchangeName;


@Autowired
public QueueEmailSender(AmqpTemplate mqTemplate, AmqpAdmin admin,
                        @Value("${message-queue.exchanges.emailMessageExchangeName}") String exchange,
                        @Value("${message-queue.names.emailMessageQueueName}") String queue){
    this.mqTemplate = mqTemplate;
    this.mqAdmin = admin;
    this.exchangeName = exchange;
    this.queueName = queue;
    createExchangeAndQueue();
}


@Override
public void send(EmailRequestDto email){
    try {
        log.info("sending mail with params:" + email.getReplyTo());
        sendMessage(email);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("can't send email to queue. message was {}", email, e);
    }
}

private void sendMessage(Object email) {
    mqTemplate.convertAndSend(exchangeName, queueName, email);
}

private void createExchangeAndQueue() {
    Exchange exchange = new DirectExchange(exchangeName, true, false);
    Queue queue = new Queue(queueName, true, false, false);
    System.out.println("Declaring exchange with rabbit admin");
    mqAdmin.declareExchange(exchange);
    mqAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
    mqAdmin.declareBinding(new Binding(queueName, Binding.DestinationType.QUEUE, exchangeName, queueName, null));
}
}
```

this is the test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class EmailSenderIT {

@Autowired
private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

@Autowired
private RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin;

@Autowired
private EmailSender emailSender;

private String queueName = "email.message.test";

private String exchangeName = "email.exchange.test";

@Before
public void setup() {
    Queue queue = new Queue(queueName, true,
            false, false);
    Exchange exchange = new DirectExchange(exchangeName, true, false);
    rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
    rabbitAdmin.declareExchange(exchange);
    rabbitAdmin.declareBinding(new Binding(queueName, Binding.DestinationType.QUEUE, exchangeName, queueName, null));

    rabbitAdmin.purgeQueue(queueName, false);
}

@Test
public void queueMessageSentWhenWhenRequestIsMade() {
    String address = "a@g.com";
    emailSender.send(EmailRequestDto.builder().from(ContactInfoDto.builder().address(address).build()).build());

    EmailRequestDto msg = rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert(queueName, 2000L, new ParameterizedTypeReference<EmailRequestDto>() { });
    Assert.assertEquals(address, msg.getFrom().getAddress());
}
```

this is the class that defines the beans:

```
@Configuration
public class MQConfig {

@Bean
public AbstractConnectionFactory connectionFactory(MQConfigParams configurationParams){
    AbstractConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(configurationParams.getVirtualHost());
    connectionFactory.setPassword(configurationParams.getPassword());
    connectionFactory.setUsername(configurationParams.getUserName());
    connectionFactory.setHost(configurationParams.getHost());
    System.out.println("creating rabbit connection factory!");
    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(AbstractConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(AbstractConnectionFactory connectionFactory){
    System.out.println("creating rabbit template!");
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
    return rabbitTemplate;
}

@Bean
public AmqpAdmin rabbitAdmin(AbstractConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    System.out.println("creating rabbit admin!");
    return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
}

}
```

I am using Spring `1.5.9.RELEASE` and rabbit and amqp `2.0.1.RELEASE`

another thing, if I run the app locally it does able to start without any problem, and if I initialise `RabbitAdmin` and `RabbitTemplate` without using Spring in the `QueueEmailSender` constructor the test passes.

Help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution!
It is a bug in the RabbitAdmin Implementation, details in this
[issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/734)

The issue is resolved, so as the recommendation goes I added a flag in my code in `MQConfig`:

```
@Bean
public AmqpAdmin rabbitAdmin(AbstractConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RabbitAdmin admin = new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
    admin.setDeclareCollections(false);
    return admin;
}
```

I also changed the version I am using to:

`compile group: 'org.springframework.amqp', name: 'spring-rabbit', version: '2.0.3.RELEASE'`

`compile group: 'org.springframework.amqp', name: 'spring-amqp', version: '2.0.3.RELEASE'`

Answer (score 0):

Edit - 
Not an NPE, my bad taking a look at Spring's source code, but I'm curious to which line is EmailSenderIt.java:45

It looks like your

```
rabbitAdmin.declareBinding(new Binding(queueName, Binding.DestinationType.QUEUE, exchangeName, queueName, null));
```

would throw a NPE as your arguments (https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/core/Binding.html#getArguments-- ) are "null".
This log should point to the same line

> "at
>   it.com.my.app.mgmt.user.EmailSenderIT.setup(EmailSenderIT.java:45)"

Comment: It does not get to this point. the exception thrown at this line in the test: `mqAdmin.declareQueue(queue);`. and the parameters are not null anyway, they are assigned with `@Value`

Comment: Yes my bad, looking at the stacktrace it comes from the following piece of code :
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/v2.0.1.RELEASE/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitAdmin.java#L438 
You may get a better insight applying a breakpoint around this to understand why it's throwing this (especially what's returned from "this.applicationContext.getBeansOfType(Collection.class, false, false).values()")
Your applicationContext may be bogus

Comment: Indeed it throws at this line. but I don't really know what that means. all the collections that the code tries to get are returned empty, but again I don't know why. About the application context, I don't think it is a problem because if I start the application locally (not through running the test) it does start without exceptions. My guess, it is something with the dependencies that miss-match but I have no clue what. Thanks for the help though!